# Delay não funciona, alguém pode me ajudar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estava programando um simples perfil e estou querendo colocar um delay depois do 'mouseenter' assim que passar o mouse entra esse 'mouseenter' e junto com delay para mostrar uma caixa que se chama '.user_widget' estou usando:

addClass e removeClass;

Css:

```
.user_widget {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: relative;
    top: 39px;
    width: 210px;
    height: 305px;
    z-index: 4;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}
.ativo {
    display: block !important;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)!important;
}
.desativado {
    display: none !important;
}
```

HTML e JavaScript:

```
<div class="user_widget desativado">    

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".user").click(function(){
    $('.user_widget').addClass('desativado');
    $('.user_widget').removeClass('ativo');
    $('.user').removeClass('ativo');
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".user").mouseenter(function(){

    $('.user_widget').removeClass('desativado');
    $('.user').addClass('ativo');
    $('.user_widget').addClass('ativo');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere a sua função mouseenter para ficar assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     //variavel global 
     var delay = 2000; 

     function mouseEnter(){
        $('.user_widget').removeClass('desativado');
        $('.user').addClass('ativo');
        $('.user_widget').addClass('ativo');
     }
</script>
```

E para a chamada, você coloca no seu elemento "user" o comando chamando a função desta maneira:

```
onmouseover="setTimeout(mouseEnter,delay);"
```

Comment: Olá Rafa, só que tipo cara, estou usando background para trocar a cor do user atrás quando entrar o mouseenter, só que está muito rápido;  Olha um print: http://prntscr.com/fnd18r sou novato em javascript ainda :/

Comment: ok, dei uma mudada, da uma olhada nesse jeito, bem simples e faz o que você quer

Comment: Então Rafa eu coloquei assim: <div class="user" onmouseenter="setTimeout(mouseEnter,delay);"> Só que não aconteceu nada quando passo o mouse.

Comment: substitua por onmouseover="javascript:setTimeout(mouseEnter,delay);"

Comment: Não acontece nada, http://prntscr.com/fnd87s , erro no javascript : http://prntscr.com/fnd8jr

Comment: manda um print da classe "user"

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fnda1m

Comment: quais são os atributos da sua classe user? você tem um css pra ela?

Comment: .user {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.76);
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 7;
    top: 14px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 29px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 13px;
    padding-top: 8px;
 left: 1px;
}

Comment: Rafa descobri, tu esqueceu de fechar mano kk,                 $('.user_widget').addClass('ativo');
    };
</script>

Comment: ok vou editar a resposta, se funcionou, indique a resposta como solução

Comment: Só que tem mais uma mano, tu viu que usei o click também? assim que dou esse hover, quero que ele fique ativo, e depois eu clico e ele fecha, consegue me ajudar nisso?

Comment: isso é porque a sua classe "desativado" está recebendo um "display:none;" sendo assim, ele vai fazer o elemento desaparecer

Comment: Só que usando o javascript, dou um .click nele e adiciono class "ativo" com "display: block", eu coloquei assim, só que quando eu tiro o mouse o onmouseover continua com o efeito dele.

Comment: esses dois métodos funcionam de formas diferentes, leia a documentação do jquery primeiro, depois tente refazer a sua pergunta https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/ https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Eu vou dar uma olhada Rafa, obrigado, o que eu quero é um delay assim que passar o mouse por cima do "user", um delay de 1s, só que eu quero deixar o "user_widget" ativo sem fechar, e depois quando eu clicar no "user" de novo ele fecha com "display: none" que seria a class "desativado".

Answer (score 0):

Gente deve ser um código simples que eu não estou conseguindo fazer, o que eu quero fazer é tipo assim, quando passar o mouse por cima da class "user" que seria "mouseenter" iria ativar a class "ativado" e remover a class "desativado";

A class "ativado" é "display: block" e a class "desativado" é a "display: none", no incio eu coloquei para não aparecer que seria "user_widget desativado" então quando passa o mouse ativa a chamada "mouseenter" e ficaria assim "user_widget ativado", então tu bem, o que eu quero é um delay nele de 1s, porque está aparecendo muito rápido, mais quero manter as duas chamadas a de "mouseenter" e a de "click" que é quando clicar no "user" remover o "ativado" e adicionar "desativado" de volta.